# dockerize django apache developer environment

Tags: django, apache, docker

I tried to dockerize my django/apache web application.

In the big picture the dockerization worked out.
For deployment Annot is running in 3 containers. The apache_annot container holds the apache server and the postgresql database The media_annot container serves as web application media folder. The annot container holds the django python related code.
For development only 2 containers are needed: the apache_annot container and media_annot container. The django and python related code is placed into a directory at the host machine. apache_annot then simply mounts this directory as a data volume under /var/www/annot/.

Here the link to the Docker files: 
https://gitlab.com/biotransistor/dock/tree/master

**Issue**:
Even the dockerized version works, it seems not to be done the real docker way.
Most annoying issue: Every time apache is restarted (which happens a lot in development) the apache_annot container and as such the whole web application stops.
To continuer apache_annot have to be restarted:

```
docker exec -ti apache_annot /bin/bash
```

Then postgresql database have to be restarted:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

And cd into /var/www/annot/ to execute django development specific python code like:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations.
```

It is nearly not possible to do development with this solution.

I can not be the only one who like to use a dockerize django apache developer environment. What do I do wrong?

Is there a way to run apache_annot so that the apache daemon can be rebooted without shouting down the apache_annot docker container?

Comment: I haven't worked with python, but judging from the configuration of Apache, python is tightly coupled with Apache. I'd switch to a solution with a stand alone python webserver (such as tornado) and a proxy webserver in front, such as nginx, varnish or even Apache.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Maybe the way to go is really to decouple even more parts into single container. One for the postgresql database and one for the djnago / pyhon code as such. 
Apache is conned to python by the mod_wsgi module (https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi).

Comment: I recommend uwsgi + nginx + postgresql + django. This is a common setup and there are lots of guides and tutorials on how to set it up.

Comment: In the meanwhile I was able to properly dockerize my django application with a ***nginx + (gunicorn + django) + postgesql*** setting following this excellent [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) from Michael Herman.

This is the link to the tutorial's [source code](https://github.com/realpython/dockerizing-django). 

The setting might be quit similar to what Håken Lid and  Mzedeler suggested. 
I see this issue as closed. Thanks!